# Jquery - вся страница черно-белая

Tags: jquery, javascript

Всем доброго времени суток. Нужно реализовать задачу - по открытию сайта страница полностью должна быть неактивной и черно-белой. После клика, она должна плавно стать цветной и активной.
Есть ли какие-либо решения?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Натяните на всю страницу блок с абсолютным позиционированием, задайте для блока стили

```
.wrapper {
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
  -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  filter: gray;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
}
```

при клике заанимируйте плавное изменение прозрачности opacity до 0, затем добавьте блоку `display: none`, чтобы можно было нажимать на кнопочки и пользоваться всеми активными элементами.